# disk size smaller than partition

Tags: partitioning, disk, disk-usage

I just set up a VM with Ubuntu 20.04.1, after setting up everything I realized that somehow the Disk Size is smaller than what I attached to it.

output of lsblk:

```
NAME                      FSTYPE       SIZE MOUNTPOINT        LABEL
fd0                                      4K
loop0                     squashfs    71.3M /snap/lxd/16099
loop1                     squashfs      55M /snap/core18/1880
loop2                     squashfs    29.9M /snap/snapd/8542
sda                                    500G
├─sda1                                   1M
├─sda2                    ext4           1G /boot
└─sda3                    LVM2_member  499G
  └─ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv ext4         200G /
sr0                                   1024M
```

sda provides 500GB of Space, but only assigns 200 to /.
How can I solve this?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you have 500 GB of space but you assigned 200 GB. You can easily assign the rest of the disk to another partition. Firstly elevate to a root shell. Then execute `fdisk /dev/sda3`. That will open that device in fdisk shell session. Then type `n` and press enter in order to create a new partition. You can keep pressing enter for the question it prompts you. If you do that fdisk will automatically assign the rest of the disk to a new partition. Then type `w` and press enter to write the changes to the disk. After that you can quit the program, build a file system on it with the command `mkfs.ext4 /dev/sda4` (it will be probably sda4 but if the partition name is something else, you have to put it there instead of sda4) and mount that new partition to your main file system